# Pointers in C not working as desired

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to work through Harvard's CS50 problem set and I find myself stuck on a very basic greedy problem of finding the least number of coins for given change if the coins are only available in denominations of 25c, 10c, 5c and 1c. While pointers are not really needed for this problem and even having a separate function is an overkill probably, I'm trying to get a better understanding of pointers by implementing it here, however, I don't get the desired output for 'coins' for some reason. The printf statements after before and after function calls are for debugging purposes. A sample output is given after the code.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

void denomination(float* change, int* coins, int den);

int main(void){

    float change;
    do{
        printf("How much change is owed?\n");
        change = GetFloat();
    }while(change < 0);

    int coins; //number of coins in total to be given in change

    if(change == 0){
        coins = 0;
        printf("%d\n", coins);
    }else{
        change = change * 100; //converting to cents
        denomination(&change, &coins, 25);
        printf("Inside else:: Change: %f, Coins: %d\n", change, coins);
        denomination(&change, &coins, 10);
        printf("Inside else:: Change: %f, Coins: %d\n", change, coins);
        denomination(&change, &coins, 5);
        printf("Inside else:: Change: %f, Coins: %d\n", change, coins);
        denomination(&change, &coins, 1);
        printf("Inside else:: Change: %f, Coins: %d\n", change, coins);
        printf("%d\n", coins);
    }
    return 0;
}

void denomination(float* change, int* coins, int den){
    int tmp; 
    tmp = (*change/den);
    printf("Temp: %d\n", tmp);
    *coins = *coins + tmp;
    *change = *change - (tmp*den);
}
```

Here's the output:

```
How much change is owed?
0.41
Temp: 1
Inside else:: Change: 16.000000, Coins: 134516108
Temp: 1
Inside else:: Change: 6.000000, Coins: 134516109
Temp: 1
Inside else:: Change: 1.000000, Coins: 134516110
Temp: 1
Inside else:: Change: 0.000000, Coins: 134516111
134516111
```

I don't understand why 'change' works as desired but 'coins' does not.

Comment: What is the initial value of `coins`?

Comment: I noticed that `change = GetFloat();;` contains two semicolons, I know it's not a problem and perfectly acceptable, but probably not intended for readability sake.

Comment: In your else clause, initialize coins to 0 before you start using it. And FWIW, I would make the first parameter `change` an int, since you are counting integral values (cents) anyway. That avoids some problems you might encounter with floating point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of remove the while loop in function.

```
void denomination(float* change, int* coins, int den)
{
    int tmp;
    tmp = (*change/den);
    printf("Temp: %d\n", tmp);
    *coins = *coins + tmp;
    *change = *change - (tmp*den);
}
```

Because you are already dividing so getting the total number of coins only in one time.

So first of all there is no need of loop.

Then instead of only removinf one den you have to remove total amount which will be multiple of tmp coins to be given.

So Corrected the following statement in your function.

```
*change=(*change-(tmp*den));
```

Second thing initialize the coins variable.

As i think it is giving somewhat garbage value.

So initialize it with zero in main.

```
int Coins=0;
```

Comment: Why would I remove the while loop in the function? If the change passed in is 52c and the den is 25, then it has to loop through twice to get 2 25c denomination coins.

Comment: You are getting the total number of coins by using the statement "tmp = (*change/den);" which is perfect so there is no need to use loop.

Comment: Please remove the loop and correct the code as i specified. Please put your reply in comment weather you removed loop or not? as it will help others too.

Comment: I removed the loop and made the other changes you suggested. The program functions now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `while` loop must be left with a nonzero value of `change` (as the `else` branch is reached), but `coins` is initialized only in the `if` branch above. In total, the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anywhere that coins is initialized and its new value is always dependent on the previous value I could that would be the problem it look to me like its not a pointer problem